# EF5 Code First Automatic Migrations: Renaming Primary Key gives error: column names in each table must be unique

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, primary-key, rename

I have an entity `Relations` with primary key `RelId`. I would like to change this key to `RelationId`

First, I changed the Columname in SSMS:
[SQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVG1l.jpg)

Then I used (in Visual Studio) **Rename** to change the word `RelId` to `RelationId`, in all references.

I thought that this *change in the database and in the code*, would convince my code to work with the new named Primary Key, but alas following error arises when I run the Project:

> column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'RelationId' in table 'dbo.Relations' is specified more than once.

Of course, this isn't the case. In the table the column `RelationId` exists only once. It's like EF5 is trying to add another column with the same name.

Can anyone explain me why this error occurs and how to fix it?

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {

        //Database.SetInitializer<OefenfirmaContext>(new OefenfirmaDropCreateAndSeed());
        Database.SetInitializer<OefenfirmaContext>(new OefenfirmaDropCreateAndSeed());

        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(ShoppingCart), new CartModelBinder());
    }
```

and the class OefenfirmaDropCreateAndSeed (not seeding anymore):

```
public class OefenfirmaDropCreateAndSeed : 
    MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<OefenfirmaContext, Migrations.Configuration>
{
}
```

Comment: Is there some code that recreates the dbo.Relations or tries to rename a column?

Comment: If you want Code First, you should change your code first (not the database) and let migrations or initializers make the database changes. Now you probably have some sort of mismatch between the models and database. Any fluent configuration code out there?

Comment: Not really,  Just a reference in global.asax. I'll edit the question and post the global asax

Comment: @SteveGreene, no fluent, just data annotiations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Add-Migrations right? then, you need not update on the database side manually using manual scripts. You should do it in the Add-Migration scripts alone. If you manually run the scripts for rename column in the database side then Existing system generated MigrationScripts and the Database will be in out of sync. So, You will end up with an error while running/rollback the new/old migration scripts. As per my understanding, please try out the following steps

**Step 1:** Rename the Primary key of the Model Class (**RelId to RelationId) in Visual Studio Code.**

**Step 2:** Run the **Add-Migration RenameMyColumn** in **Package Manager Console.** The system will generate the Migrationscripts based on the model changes like below.

**Note:** Please verifies system generated **AddColumn** and **DropColumn** instead of **RenameColumn** scripts like below in the system generated migration scripts. If yes, Please remove the AddColumn and DropColumn scripts manually and add the **RenameColumn()** scripts in the **up()** and **down()** methods for the renamed Primary key property.

```
namespace MyProject.Model.Migrations
{
   using System;
   using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

   public partial class RenameMyColumn : DbMigration
   {
     public override void Up()
     {
        // Remove the following auto-generated lines(Note:These scripts generated for an example purpose not for primary key)
        AddColumn("dbo.MyTable", "NewColumn", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50));
        DropColumn("dbo.MyTable", "OldColumn");

        // Add this line
        RenameColumn("dbo.MyTable", "OldColumn", "NewColumn");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        // Remove the following auto-generated lines(Note:These scripts generated for an example purpose not for primary key)
        AddColumn("dbo.MyTable", "OldColumn", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50));
        DropColumn("dbo.MyTable", "NewColumn");

        // Add this line
        RenameColumn("dbo.MyTable", "NewColumn", "OldColumn");
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this might help you to move forward!

Comment: AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
            ContextKey = "Mvc.OefenfirmaCMS.Lib.Data.OefenfirmaContext";
        }

Comment: Sorry, I 'entered' too soon. I meant that Automatic Migrations is enabled. Do you suggest that I turn this of and use manual migrations?

Comment: No, Please go with the "Automatic Migrations is enabled". I meant you should not manually run the rawscripts for renaming the primary key of the Table on the database side. You have to follow the above steps which I mentioned.

Comment: Done. The RenameMyColumn class is changed as you proposed.  Do I have to use a command in the PM-console to execute these changes? And could you explain briefly what UP and DOWN does, please?

Comment: `Update-Database`  executed the changes. Thanks for your support Vignesh! You really helped me.

Comment: Yes, Please run the update-database command to apply the migration scripts into the Database. As you asked, Up() Method will be called when   we run the update-database whenever running the pending migration scripts. Down() will be used to roll back/delete the stored procedure automatically in migration script.